# How to solve differential equation 2. order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

With which method I can get particular solution of this equation? I was thinking about guessing method, but not sure which guess exactly I should use.

$$\cos(t)x''+\cos(t)x-1=0$$

Comment: **Hint:** Divide by the cosine term, solve the homogeneous and then use Variation of Parameters.

Comment: @Moo   great. Got it!